# Can I use Set collection to eliminate duplicate by two different equals?

Tags: java, collections, set, equals

I have a project in Java.  First I need to create a collection with no duplicates in the name of object & its number, so I use the Set collection and this equals method:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    Course<?> c=(Course<?>)obj;
    return (c.number==number&& c.Name.equals(Name));
}
```

next ..i need to create collection of the same object but now i need to insure that only his name is not duplicate. so its a problem because i cant use two diffrents methods of equals 
what can i do??

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a TreeSet instead and specifying the comparator to use for that specific set instead of overriding `equals`.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet-java.util.Comparator-

If you don't want them actually sorted, but just remove dupes, the comparator just has to return 0 when they are equal.

```
TreeSet<Course> tree1 = new TreeSet<Course>((c1, c2) -> c1.number==c2.number && c1.Name.equals(c2.Name) ? 0 : 1);
```

and

```
TreeSet<Course> tree2 = new TreeSet<Course>((c1, c2) -> c1.Name.equals(c2.Name) ? 0 : 1);
```

Comment: but comparator returning int for comparing not to ignor duplicates..its only sort the objects in the treeset by the value it returning in some order i choose.. isnt it??

Comment: A TreeSet is a set. If two objects are compared to be equal (i.e. the comparator returned 0) then the new value will be considered a duplicate and excluded. If the comparator returns anything other than zero, they will not be duplicates and both will be in the set. So yes, normally it's used for sorting, but in this case, you can use it to detect duplicates

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your class in a wrapper class that will implement the `hashcode` and `equals` functions the way you want:

```
public NameWrapper {
    private Course c;

    public NameWrapper(Course c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public void equals(Object other) {
        // ...
        return this.name.equals(other.name);
    }

    // + hashCode
    // + getter
}

// Similarly with number and name wrapper
```

And then you can wrap, distinct and unwrap your elements:

```
Collection<Course> courses = // ...
Collection<Course> distincts = 
    courses.stream()
           .map(NameWrapper::new)             // wrap
           .distinct()
           .map(NameWrapper::getCourse)       // unwrap
           .map(NumberNameWrapper::new)       // wrap
           .distinct()
           .map(NumberNameWrapper::getCourse) // unwrap
           .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy, but probably not really great solution would be to use two specific wrapper classes that each have **different** equals methods.

And instead of directly using your own class, you put objects of those "wrapper" classes into those collections.

Like:

```
class Course { ... your class

class CourseWrapperForName {
   Course wrappedCourse; 
...
   Course getWrappedCourse() { return wrappedCourse; }
   @Override 
   public boolean equals(Object other) {
   ... compares names

class CourseWrapperForNumber {
   Course wrappedCourse; 
...
   @Override 
   public boolean equals(Object other) {
   ... compares numbers
```

Now, eliminating duplicates can be done by putting your Course objects into the corresponding wrapper; adding wrappers to Sets; and then retrieving the course.

But obviously, that is a lot of boilerplate; and more reasonable solutions could be

A) using a TreeSet with a different

B) the later can be enhanced with a lot of black lambda magic; there is a nice [presentation](http://2016.java-forum-stuttgart.de/_data/D4_Wiedeking.pdf) how to do that (it is in German, but mainly code; the interesting part starts at page 40).

Answer (score 0):

I would take the `Set<Course>` with this equals method implemented (that will give me the course which are unique in name & number both).

Further, I would make a subclass of Course 'SubCourse' and override the equals method:

```
class SubCourse extends Course{
    public boolean equals(Object o){
                if(o instanceof SubCourse){
                    return (this.Name.equals(((SubCourse)o).Name));
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
        }

    }
```

And then make a `Set<SubCourse>` that will give you a unique courses in terms of numbers (not in name as we excluded that condition). You need to make the instance variables of `Course` as `protected`.